# Qt menu without shadow?

Tags: qt, menu

I copied the question description below from other asked but not answered question, because this is the exactly the same one I wanna ask.

I have a QMenu with a translucent background and rounded edges (border-radius). Unfortunately, Windows 7 draws a drop shadow for this menu, which does not fit to the rounded edges. Its the shadow that would be drawn for normal rectangular menus.

Is there either - a way to completely disable drawing drop shadows for QMenu or - a way to make the shadow fit to the rounded edges ?

Here is a minimalistic example where it occurs:

```
QPushButton b("press me");
QMenu m;
m.addAction("hello"); m.addAction("world");
m.setWindowFlags(m.windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
m.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
m.setStyleSheet("background:rgba(255,0,0,50%); border-radius:5px;");
b.setMenu(&m);
b.show();
```

Right now I have to turn off the menu shadow in Windows Control panel manually to get rid of that shadow.
Actually what I want to achieve is a menu like Qt's pie menu or a menu like this one:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Blender_2.36_Screenshot.jpg
I tried the popup widget, but it gets the shadow artifact described above.
Could anyone help this out?

Comment: I think this is the case where you want to choose a non-native look and feel over the native look and feel which uses Qt per default. Qt tries to resemble the widgets of the operating system. To show a menu, Qt uses a dedicated window (it doesn't simply paint the menu on the underlying widget). The Windows operating system decides to add a shadow to this window for which Qt doesn't have any control. My only idea is to try different window flags for the QMenu. Otherwise, don't use the native QMenu and draw your own. But this gets complicated...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Say if I want to draw my own, can you give me more hint?? Thanks so much!

Comment: Create a custom Menu widget which displays your menu entries. Implement mouse hover effects to highlight the current menu item. To manage and display the items, you could create a custom MenuItem widget or just use a QStringList for the items, depends on which level of flexibility you want and how much effort you want to put into this. However, depending on your skill level, do not expect to get reasonable results in less than a couple of hours or a couple of days... But once you have this, you can extend your menu as you want. Rounded corners, drop shadow with rounded corners, animations, ...

Comment: That being said, I strongly recommend to rethink if you really want to do this only to achieve rounded corners. I told you what you *could* do to achieve this, but in my opinion it's not worth the effort. Maybe someone else knows how to tweak `QMenu` to disable the native shadow effects. Maybe there is a window flag you have overlooked.

Comment: I just tried other windowflags, and yes I get rid of the shadow , but I lost the feature that the popup window flag provide: Click screen area other than the menu area will close the menu.Is that a way to mimic these? Do I have to add close codes to all the other bg widgets??      As for drawing the menu all by myself, the main issue, is where I gonna paint on? If I paint on the widget who should own these menus, the menus won't go out of the frame of that widget. So I have to open a fullscreen transparent widget and paint my menu as it's contents?

Comment: As for drawing the menus by yourself: I don't think you can get rid of the issue that you can not draw outside of your main widget. At least not unless you make it a window on its own. As for playing with the window flags: I'm sorry, I don't know that much about the window flags. I just guessed that there has to be an option to suppress the shadow.

Comment: I think you could/should just post an answer to your own question telling which window flag you needed to set/unset to get rid of the shadow and also explain the drawbacks. Then I can upvote it and any future visitor ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Vista and higher, I wanted a menu with normal window shadow. So I had to do two things:

1. Remove `CS_DROPSHADOW` from the menu `HWND`'s `WNDCLASS` that Qt is adding deep down in the core.
2. Add shadow using DWM APIs.

The trick is to capture `QEvent::WinIdChange` to get the `HWND` handle to the menu window, and then to use `GetClassLong` / `SetClassLong` to remove `CS_DROPSHADOW` flag. I'm doing this only once (by using a `static bool`), as the`WNDCLASS` is always the same for all menus. This might lead into a problem if part of your app wants to show the menu shadows and other does not.

I have subclassed the `QMenu` and I'm always using my overriden class when creating menus

```
Menu * my_menu = new Menu(tr("&File"));
mainMenu->addMenu(my_menu);
```

Here's the whole code, enjoy:

menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <QMenu>

class Menu : public QMenu
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Menu(QWidget *parent = 0);
    explicit Menu(const QString & title);

protected:
    virtual bool event(QEvent *event);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // MENU_H
```

menu.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "dwmapi.lib" )
#include "dwmapi.h"

Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMenu(parent)
{

}

Menu::Menu(const QString &title) :
    QMenu(title)
{

}



bool Menu::event(QEvent *event)
{
    static bool class_amended = false;
    if (event->type() == QEvent::WinIdChange)
    {
        HWND hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(winId());
        if (class_amended == false)
        {
            class_amended = true;
            DWORD class_style = ::GetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_STYLE);
            class_style &= ~CS_DROPSHADOW;
            ::SetClassLong(hwnd, GCL_STYLE, class_style);
        }
        DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY val = DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
        ::DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &val, sizeof(DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY));

        // This will turn OFF the shadow
        // MARGINS m = {0};
        // This will turn ON the shadow
        MARGINS m = {-1};
        HRESULT hr = ::DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &m);
        if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            //do more things
        }
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the Qt::popup flag to get rid of the shadow. 
And I have to add close codes to any other background UI.  These have been more extra work, but I got what I want :)